# Same Site Cookie Attribute for go not being set after hosted by Heroku

Tags: rest, google-chrome, go, heroku, cookies

I have been trying to set up a rest api using Go. Everything works fine and the rest api is working and for authentication purposes, I am using JWT-based authentication and sending a http-Only cookie for successful sign in requests. I am using cross sites for frontend and backend so everything is cors enabled.

This is the config of the http cookie

```
http.SetCookie(w , &http.Cookie{
        Name : "session_token",
        Value : sessionToken,
        Expires : time.Now().Add( 1 * time.Hour ),
        HttpOnly: true,
        MaxAge :2600000,
        SameSite: 4, 
        Secure :true, 
    })
```

`SameSite : 4` signifies SameSite: None in the cookie string .For reference :https://golang.org/src/net/http/cookie.go

When I test my app locally by `curl`, the set-Cookie has the SameSite attribute, but when i deploy the app on Heroku, the SameSite attribute disappears and is no longer there. I absolutely need the SameSite attribute due to CSRF-forgery rules by chrome.

I have no clue how to solve this, any help in this will be highly appreciated.